# sql insert value from another table with original nulls but not unmatched entries

Tags: sql, null, sql-insert

OK. So this is a hard one to explain, but I am replacing the type of a foreign key in a database. To do this I need to update the values in a table that references it. That is all fine and good, and nice and easy to do.

I'm inserting this stuff into a temporary table which will replace the original table, but the `insert` query isn't at all difficult, it's the `select` that I get the values from.

However, I also want to keep any entries where the original reference was NULL. Also not hard, I could use a Left Inner Join for that.
But we're not done yet: I don't want the entries for which there is no match in the second table. I've been dinking around with this for 2 hours now, and am no closer to figuring this out than I am to the moon.

Let me give you an example data set:

```
____________________________
| Inventory  ||  Customer  |
|============||============|
| ID   Cust  || ID    Name |
|------------||------------|
|  1     A   ||  1     A   |
|  2     B   ||  2     B   |
|  3     E   ||  3     C   |
|  4   NULL  ||  4     D   |
|____________||____________|
```

Let's say the database used to use the `Customer.Name` field as its Primary Key, and I need to change it to a standard `int identity(1,1) not null` ID. I've added the field with no issues in the Customer table, and kept the Name because I need it for other stuff. I have had no trouble with this in all the tables that do not allow NULLs, but since the "Inventory" table allows something to be associated with No customer, I'm running into troubles.
If I did a left inner join, my results would be:

```
______________
|   Results  |
|============|
| ID   Cust  |
|------------|
|  1     1   |
|  2     2   |
|  3   NULL  |
|  4   NULL  |
|____________|
```

However, Inventory #3 was referencing a customer which does not exist. I want that to be filtered out.
This database is my development database, where I hack, slash, and destroy things with wanton disregard for validity. So a lot of links in these tables are no longer valid.
The next step is replicating this process in the beta-testing environment, where bad records *shouldn't* exist, but I can't guarantee that. So I'd like to keep the filter, if possible.

The query I have right now is using a sub-query to find all rows in `Inventory` whose `CustID` either exists in `Customers`, or `is null`. It then tries to only grab the value from those rows which the subquery found. Here's the translated query:

```
insert into results
(
    ID,
    Cust
)
select
    inv.ID, cust.ID
from Inventory inv, Customer cust
where inv.ID in 
    (
        select inv.ID from Inventory inv, Customer cust
        where inv.Cust is null
        or cust.Name = inv.Cust
    )
and cust.Name = inv.Cust
```

But, as I'm sure you can see, this query isn't right. I've tried using 2, 3 subqueries, inner joins, left joins, bleh. The results of this query, and many others I've tried (that weren't horribly, horribly wrong) are:

```
______________
|   Results  |
|============|
| ID   Cust  |
|------------|
|  1     1   |
|  2     2   |
|____________|
```

Which is essentially an inner-join. Considering my actual data has around 1100 records which have NULL values in that field, I don't think truncating them is the answer.

The answer I'm looking for is:

```
______________
|   Results  |
|============|
| ID   Cust  |
|------------|
|  1     1   |
|  2     2   |
|  4   NULL  |
|____________|
```

The trickiest part of this insert into select is the fact that I'm looking to insert either a value from another table, or essentially a value from this table or the literal NULL. That just isn't something I know how to do; I'm still getting the hang of SQL.

Since I'm inserting the results of this query into a table, I've considered doing the insert using a select which leaves out the NULL values and un-matched records, then going back through and adding in all the NULL records, but I really want to learn how to do the more advanced queries like this.

So do any of yous folks have any ideas? 'Cause I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a union?

Select all records where ID and Cust match and union that with all records where ID matches and inventory.cust is null.

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was something terribly simple. Thanks a million!
I ended up doing just that. `select inv.ID, cust.ID from Inventory inv, Customer cust where inv.Cust = cust.Name` UNIONed with `select inv.ID, inv.Cust from Inventory inv where inv.Cust is null` did the trick.